# Any change window#mouseOver got ignored?

Tags: javascript

**window#mouseOver** got ignored.
When elementB got rendered, I add a **mousemove**  handler  to window object using capture flag.
And in element A, the **pointermove** handler is registered before aboved action.

When i move mouse around element A, only **pointermove** got fired.

Any idea? I use capture option for mousemove handler onto window object.
It should be always firing first. But now it's got ignored.
In the codebase, it doesn't do removeListner in any place.
Any idea will be appreciating.

I'm working on a big project with NDA, could not share with the code.

[image]

Comment: We don't want full code, just how you binded the listeners. Or else make sample fiddle which will replicate your issue so that we can figure out what is exactly wrong

Comment: It would be great if you can create a runnable example that replicates this problem, doesn't have to be from your actual code.

Comment: By the way, I tried to replicate your example, with a parent and a child, a `mousemove` on the window and a `pointermove` on the parent, and both of them are firing just fine.